# nginx no longer rewrites redirect location when ssl is enabled

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I setup nginx as a reverse proxy, to access a service running on a different host and add ssl encryption. I am using the following configuration:

```
server {
  listen 9000 ssl;
  server_name my.domain.de;

  ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
  ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout  10m;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location /service/ {
    proxy_pass  http://remote_host:8999/;

    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port    $server_port;
  }
}
```

When I try to open the URL `https://my.domain.de:9000/service/`, the response is a 302 redirect with the Location header set to `https://remote_host:8999/ui` but it should be `https://my.domain.de:9000/service/ui`.

When I deactivate ssl by changing the line `listen 9000 ssl;` to `listen 9000;` it works as expected.

I already tried explicitly specifying `proxy_redirect http://remote_host:8999/ https://my.domain.de:9000/service/;`, which should be the default behavior anyway afaik, but it didn't help.

BTW: Accessing `https://my.domain.de:9000/service/ui` directly also works fine. The only problem is nginx not correctly replacing the Location header in the 302 response coming from the remote host.

It's not only annoying that the redirect does not work, but I also don't like that the hostname of the proxied server gets exposed that way.

Comment: It seems that your remote host is writing `https` in the Location header, which means it doesn't match. Try: `proxy_redirect https://remote_host:8999/ https://my.domain.de:9000/service/;`

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves it.
Also I notice I can instead omit the line setting `X-Forwarded-Proto`. That way the remote server doesn't use https in the Location header and therefore the default `proxy_redirect` configuration applies.